# how i get list of one week data with count and date

Tags: c#, list, date, .net-core

I have try to get list of data for last on week date with count .the problem is if the count zero the date not in that list but i want all seven days with count

```
lastWeekRegisterStatistic1 = dbContext.MtMUsers.Join(dbContext.MtLogRegistrationAudits,
    U => U.EmployeeId,
    Ru => Ru.UserId,
    (U, Ru) => new { U = U, Ru = Ru })
    .Where(x => x.Ru.Status != null && 
           x.Ru.Status.ToLower() == "success" &&
           x.Ru.LoggedDate.Value.Date >= dt.Date &&
           x.Ru.LoggedDate.Value.Date <= dt.AddDays(6).Date &&
           x.U.IsMobileUser != 0 && 
           (request.clientIds == null || 
            request.clientIds.Count == 0 ||
            request.clientIds.Contains(x.U.ClientId)) &&
           (request.assetIds == null || 
            request.assetIds.Count == 0 ||
            request.assetIds.Contains(x.U.AssetId)) &&
           ((request.startDate == null && request.endDate == null) ||
            (request.startDate <= x.U.CreatedDate && request.endDate >= x.U.CreatedDate)))
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.Ru.LoggedDate.Value.Date }).OrderByDescending(o => o.Count())
    .Select(s => new lastWeekStatisticsObject
    {
        date = s.Key.Date,
        userCount = s.Count()
    }).OrderBy(o => o.date).ToList();
```

this is my code
result is

```
"lastWeekStatistics": [
            {
                "date": "2022-11-10T00:00:00",
                "userCount": 166
            },
            {
                "date": "2022-11-11T00:00:00",
                "userCount": 132
            },
            {
                "date": "2022-11-12T00:00:00",
                "userCount": 17
            }
```

I only get three date data because balance date don't have data

I want all the seven days with date and count

Comment: When you create a loop from you startdate ('2022-11-07', when you week starts on mondays) to the last day of the week, you should be able to add the missing days, with a userCount of 0.

Comment: You can't have you cake and pie too.  You have filtered a lot of data from your output with the WHERE so you are not getting all the dates.  Does the dbContext contain all the missing dates.  If not than you have to use Luuk solution.  The results can be confusing if you add the missing dates without an explanation.  So you may want to remove clientIds and assetids from the where and put these fields into the output so it is obvious that not transactions for the client and asset occurred on these dates.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! generally, sql queries do not generate data out of thin air. for instance `.GroupBy(g => new { g.Ru.LoggedDate.Value.Date })` will only have dates which exists after your very long `Where` applied. it would be easier for you to print zeroes later on on the UI or appended into the resulting list later on.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just append the non-existing dates **after** the query manifested as `List`?

```
var emptyDates = Enumerable.Range(0, 6)
     .Select(x => dt.Date.AddDays(x))
     .Where(x => 
      !lastWeekRegisterStatistic1
        .Select(y => y.date)
        .Contains(x))
     .Select(x => new lastWeekStatisticsObject()
      {
        date = x,
        userCount = 0
      });
```

Then you can append the result using normal `List` operation:

```
lastWeekRegisterStatistic1.Add(emptyDates);
```

Don't forget to sort the `List` though!

Comment: Thaks Bagus Tesa its actually help me . Its solve my rquirement thanks bagus